# Avoid apostrophe when inserting a formula with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to insert an Index-Match array formula into a cell. My problem is, I need to use a variable inside the formula, and that results in a cell reference in the formula that gets surrounded by apostrophes. I'll explain myself better with an example:

This is the code I have so far:

```
Cells(loop, "H").value = "=INDEX('Tab Asistencias'!R1C1:R20000C4,MATCH(1,('Tab Asistencias'!R1C2:R20000C2=R2C2)*('Tab Asistencias'!R1C1:R20000C1=E" & loop & "),0),4)"
```

And, when the formula is already inserted in cell H1 it looks like this:

=INDICE('Tab Asistencias'!$A$1:$D$20000;COINCIDIR(1;('Tab Asistencias'!$B$1:$B$20000=$B$2)*('Tab Asistencias'!$A$1:$A$20000='E2');0);4)

The two apostrophes in the E2 cell reference almost at the end of the formula are the ones that bother me. Because of that Excel doesn't recognize E2 as a valid cell reference.

I'm doing this on a spanish version of Excel (it must be done that way).

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Easiest way to figure out things in VBA is to use Record Macro and check the generated code. You will have to use `.FormulaArray =` instead of `.Value =`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Already tried that, and using Evaluate but it didn't work neither. I'm going to insert the formula as a value only and then use the SendKey method to simulate pressing F2, and then Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rename Loop because in the English version of the VBA Loop is a reserved word.

Where loop = 2; `E" & loop & "` is being evaluated as `'E2'` because you are mixing R1C1 style notation with A1 style notation.

Here I use x instead of loop and `R" & x & "C5` to get the proper refernce.

```
Cells(x, "H").Value = "=INDEX('Tab Asistencias'!R1C1:R20000C4,MATCH(1,('Tab Asistencias'!R1C2:R20000C2=R2C2)*('Tab Asistencias'!R1C1:R20000C1=R" & x & "C5),0),4)"
```

Output:

`=INDEX('Tab Asistencias'!$A$1:$D$20000,MATCH(1,('Tab Asistencias'!$B$1:$B$20000=$B$2)*('Tab Asistencias'!$A$1:$A$20000=$E$10),0),4)`

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked great.